# Is development of Dia (diagram software) permanently halted?

Tags: open-source, diagram, dia

As far as I can tell there hasn't been any releases in 5+ years. Is it a dead project, or is there a fork of it somewhere with ongoing development?

It's a decent piece of software, but it's still missing at least one must have (to me) feature: the ability to rotate objects.

Comment: Time to contact the author(s).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support question. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Dia development is not halted.

The Dia editor has been overtaken by GNOME. Its hosted at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia and during first half of 2021 it had cca 20 commits from cca 10 different people.

Thus, Dia is still much alive.

Answer (score 3):

There have been no updates for years, and the developers haven't responded to inquiries, so the project does appear dead.

I haven't found any forks or any true open source alternatives. Inkscape can be used to accomplish anything that Dia can or should do, but it's a bit like using c++ to write and format a word document.

**Edit:** [draw.io](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) seems to be a decent alternative